# Regex with logical OR generates tuple with None

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to use the regex pattern `>(\S.*?)<|#{1}\s+?(\w.*)` with the method `re.findall` over the string

```
<h1 id="section">First Section</h1><a name="first section">
# Section_2
```

My expected result is two lists

```
["First Section"]
["Section_2"]
```

However, I get

```
["First Section",""]
["","Section_2"]
```

Does someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to play with HTML files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Your results are good, you ask for two capture groups so it gives you a tuple with two elements for each line.

Except parsing HTML with regex, you did nothing wrong, you'll just need one more step to process the `re.findall()` results ;)

Comment: *"...what I am doing wrong?"* You're using regex to parse HTML. This seem to be your main mistake :)

Comment: Why do you expect your regular expression to match both groups at once? The OR in the RE only needs one of the groups to match. If you want to match both at the same time, remove the OR and restructure your RE. Also, for HTML, use an HTML parser.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for you particular case. I tried to keep more or less the same structure as your regular expression with some minor changes.

```
import re  
a = '<h1 id="section">First Section</h1><a name="first section">'
b = '# Section_2'
r = re.compile(r'((?<=>)\S.*?(?=<)|(?<=#{1}\s)\w.*)')

print(r.findall(a))
print(r.findall(b))
```

The reason why you get two outputs is because you have two capturing groups - `(\S.*?)` and `(\w.*)`. Empty means that that group did not capture anything.

In the regular expression for the answer I only use one capturing group with an OR condition.